# c# linq GroupBy and Sum up only the lowerest in each group

Tags: c#, linq

This is the problem:
I have a long list of objects with properties

```
1) int Book (B)
2) int Chapter (C)
3) int Paragraph (P)
4) int TimesRead (nx)
```

each book is the sum of all it's chapters and each chapter is the sum of all it's paragraphs. Obviously only if you have read all the chapters of a book it counts for having read the whole book. The same is true for a chapter; all paragraphs have to be read to count the chapter as read.

The list of references that looks like this

```
B1 - C1 - P1 - 3x
B1 - C1 - P2 - 3x
B1 - C1 - P3 - 4x
B1 - C2 - P1 - 5x
B1 - C2 - P2 - 2x
B1 - C2 - P3 - 2x
B1 - C2 - P4 - 9x
B2 - C1 - P1 - 3x
...tens of thousands of them
```

B1C1 counts only as 3x read. B1C2 counts as 2x read because each of the paragraphs have been read 3x and 2x respectively. What I want to count is only the minimum. 
I want the sum of all the chapters how often they have been read through completely. But how do I go about summing up only the lowerest `TimesRead` for each chapter;

```
B1C1 + B1C2 + B2C1
 3   +   2  +   3
```

using linq or a loop (I'd prefer linq).

This is as far as I get but it's not correct. How do I get only the groups with the lowest `TimesRead` for each pair x.Book-x.Chapter?

```
SumTotalChaptersRead = listBookChapterParagraph
    .Where(x => x.TimesRead >= 1)
    .GroupBy(x => new Tuple<string, int>($"{x.Book}-{x.Chapter}", x.TimesRead))
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.TimesRead[.Min])
    .Sum(s => s.Key.Item2);
```

Somehow there must be a `TimesRead.Min` somewhere in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me (in LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<Info>
    {
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=1, Paragraph=1, TimesRead=3},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=1, Paragraph=2, TimesRead=3},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=1, Paragraph=3, TimesRead=4},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=2, Paragraph=1, TimesRead=5},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=2, Paragraph=2, TimesRead=2},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=2, Paragraph=3, TimesRead=2},
        new Info(){ Book=1, Chapter=2, Paragraph=4, TimesRead=9},
        new Info(){ Book=2, Chapter=1, Paragraph=1, TimesRead=3},
    };

    var query = data.GroupBy(d => new {d.Book, d.Chapter})
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Book = g.Key.Book,
        Chapter = g.Key.Chapter,
        MinTimesRead = g.Min(d => d.TimesRead)
    });

    query.Dump();
}

public class Info
{
    public int Book { get; set; }
    public int Chapter { get; set; }
    public int Paragraph { get; set; }
    public int TimesRead { get; set; }
}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

It does this by grouping on `Book` and `Chapter`, and returning an anonymous object containing the `Book`, `Chapter`, and the minimum `TimesRead` for that group.

The `Sum` of `TimesRead` is just a simple matter of `.Sum(q => q.MinTimesRead)` on that result.

LINQPad file is available [here](http://share.linqpad.net/5uaw3u.linq).

---

If you want access to the items within the groupings, change the `Select` to:

```
.Select(g => new
{
    Book = g.Key.Book,
    Chapter = g.Key.Chapter,
    MinTimesRead = g.Min(d => d.TimesRead),
    Items = g.Select(i => i)
});
```

Which will give you:

[image]
(image may be slightly out of sync with code, as I tweaked the code to be more memory efficient with larger data sets after I took the screenshot)

Comment: +1 for being elaborate. I particularly like the ability to browse `Items` for debugging. But it opened up another few options that I hadn't considered.

Comment: LINQPad is practically essential for exploring and debugging some of the more complex LINQ statements.  I highly recommend it if you aren't already using it.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t check this out right now, but wouldn’t something similar to this work?

```
SumTotalChaptersRead =
   listBookChapterParagraph.Where(x => x.TimesRead >= 1)
                           .GroupBy(x => $"{x.Book}-{x.Chapter}")
                           .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.TimesRead).First())
                           .Sum(x => x.TimesRead);
```

Comment: This works well, too and is nice and short. However, with @Bradley Uffner's answer I can do a bit more afterwards.